# Tapering a tentacle mesh with uniformly scaled suction discs

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, edit-mode

How can I taper the tentacle while maintaining the circular shape of the suckers along it's length?

I have modeled a simple tentacle using the array and curve modifier.

Imagine the tentacle as a set of cylinders with two circular suckers.

I then go to edit mode for the curve and reduce the radius of each point to achieve the tapering of the tentacle.

Everything is fine except that the suckers have an oval shape instead of the initial circular shape, especially towards the end of the tentacle where the radius of the curve point is largely reduced.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a lattice modifier deformation?  If the mesh is fine enough it might be a way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi. I tried the lattice modifier but the same. I also added a vertex group containing the suckers to exclude them from the deformer but nothing. I guess my solution is to go into edit mode for the tentacle and correct the shape manually for each sucker. But that means that i have to apply the array modifier and i need it to stretch the tentacle when i manipulate the curve.

Comment: Please place an image in your question to clarify you question. The simplest image that illustrates your problems will be fine.

Comment: Is this a highly animated mesh or a static mesh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Duplication on Faces**

Consider Proportional Editing manually or by modifier.  Curve guide with [no] radius adjustment.

[image]

Above Detail view. Blue Tentacle Curved Form Tapered.  Discs Not Tapered. I used a semi torus as a disc for this discussion.

[image]

Above the Duplication Settings for the tentacle highlighted above. Scaling is uniform for this feature.  No ellipse forms are introduced.  This feature renders duplicates and does [not] render the two original meshes.  Surprising but useful.  For the question above you need one mesh for visual rendering and one for placement of duplicated discs.  Total 2 Meshes for final render.  One mesh visible. One not visible.

[image]

The disc is parented to the other mesh, this is a requirement .

[image]

Above larger view.  Curve Highlighted.  Second set of Discs not placed on any other mesh.  This is just to show versatility of placement.  Original straight Cylinder form with no modifiers.  The two gray cubes used as the tapering objects for a Warp Modifier. I used the warp modifier, as one option, because I wanted visual interaction. You need [not] use the warp modifier. You may [proportional edit] by hand.  You may also use [shape keys].

[image]

Above show 2 (two) blue tapered meshes.  The highlighted blue mesh has the curve modifier disabled so we can see both blue meshes easily. The highlighted mesh was copied from the other and then Duplication on Faces was turned off. One blue mesh is rendered and has [no] duplication on faces.  The other other blue mesh is for placement of discs and is not rendered.  This separation of placement and render is a feature.  It is highly likely you need to use 2 meshes in the same fashion.

[image]

Above rendered image showing custom placement of discs by deletion of faces, not vertices, of the duplicator.  The viewable mesh was not changed.  2 Meshes are used as stated above.

[image]

Above the deleted faces of duplicator.

[image]

Above rendered image smoothed and using subdivision surface modifier.

**Secondary**

You can consider [Make Duplicates Real] on the duplicator to create multiple meshes and turning off face duplication on the duplicator.