# How to arrange objects along a mesh and deform them along the normal?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature

Does anyone know how to arrange objects along the mesh in blender and deform them along the mesh normals, like in this image?

[image]

Comment: Please see ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44901/tapering-a-tentacle-mesh-with-uniformly-scaled-suction-discs/44928#44928.  We hope to see your results when you are successful

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46040/how-to-fill-the-surface-of-a-mesh-with-cones-which-point-to-the-normal-do-not-o/46045#46045

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an array following a curve, so you'd look to extract an (interior) edge (of the object to follow) into a curve to array and curve the objects along.
[image][image]

hmmm... how to attach the blend file....??

Answer (score 0):

To tilt a curve vertex (or several vertices), select the vertex and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, or set the value in the N panel. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to bring back the value to 0:

[image]